# Slice a Sentence By Numbers and Words

Tags: c#

Here is my sentence:

> Hi 123 it is a 564 and 678, so let's work.

I need to slice it by numbers and words like this:

```
[0] -> "Hi "
[1] -> "123"
[2] -> " it is a "
[3] -> "564"
[4] -> " and "
[5] -> "678"
[6] -> ", so let's work."
```

I tried to split it by space `char` and join if there are numbers or not in every block of the array. But it will not a good idea and it has so much coding to join and split.

Is there any simple way even using Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to split by.

This is the regex you need:

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

It basically looks for a digit-non-digit boundary or a non-digit-digit boundary.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; // don't forget this using directive!

Regex.Split("Hi 123 it is a 564 and 678, so let's work.", @"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)");
```

Comment: is it possible to use a pattern for letters and, not numbers?

Comment: @InsideMan That wouldn't work because you have characters like `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it uses regular expressions with pattern `\d+` which means one or more nuemric digits, then it splits by strings, that match this pattern:

```
string[] sentences = {"Hi 123 it is a 564 and 678, so let's work.",
                      "123 asd asd 123",
                      "123 asd 123 asd"};
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
{
    var sliced = Regex.Split(sentences[i], @"(\d+)").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code below.

```
        String full = "Hi 123 it is a 564 and 678, so let's work.";

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string buffer = "";
        bool number_seq = false;
        int number;

        for (int i = 0; i < full.Length; i++)
        {
            String single_char = full.Substring(i, 1);
            bool isNumber = int.TryParse(single_char, out number);
            if (isNumber)
            {
                if (!number_seq)
                {
                    list.Add(buffer);
                    buffer = "";
                    number_seq = true;
                }
            }else if (number_seq)
            {
                list.Add(buffer);
                buffer = "";
                number_seq = false;
            }
            buffer += single_char;
        }
        list.Add(buffer);
```